How to improve this electronic cat fence circuit?
The circuit below is part of a cat-collar system. Details of its purpose are given because these dictate its design. The overall purpose is to keep a cat in the garden, by making a cat-collar buzzer turn on when the cat gets near to the garden perimeter.
The system was 'designed' mainly through trial and error, so I am sure it could be improved.
How can the system be simplified or improved?

The cat-collar system consists of two parts:

An off-the-shelf 27 MHz RF transmitter module (not shown) used in radio controlled models. The transmitted signal is modulated at 1 kHz (square wave).

A small, low power cat-collar circuit, which consists of 2 parts:


A) An off-the-shelf 27 MHz RF receiver module (not shown) used in radio controlled models. Its output is a 1kHz degraded square wave (it is basically a sine wave). The max amplitude is 0-2V, with an impedance of about 50k.
B) The switch circuit below, which takes the output of the RF module, and activates an (active, not passive) buzzer when the RF module 1 kHz amplitude is large.
The power is from a small (150 mAh) 3.7 V Li-po battery. The quiescent current is about 1 mA, and about 20 mA when the buzzer is on.
The 3-pin 1 MΩ pot shown actually connects across the battery terminals, with the centre pin connected to the transistor base. This pot adjusts the sensitivity of the circuit.
Operation:
When Q1 is OFF, Q2 is ON, so the buzzer turns ON.
When Q1 is ON, Q2 is OFF, so the buzzer turns OFF.
The input at C1 is 0-2V sine when the cat collar is close to the transmitter. The output of C1 is 0-800 mV. The bias of Q1 is set high to rectitify its input, so the output of Q1 is a rectified sine wave, (the 1M pot is connected across the battery, and its middle pin connects to Q1's base). The rectification removes the 'top half' of the sine wave.
When the cat collar is far from the transmitter, the signal from the RF module is small, and the DC bias keeps Q1 in an ON state, so Q2 is OFF, so the buzzer is OFF.
When the cat collar is close to the transmitter, Q1 inverts and rectifies the (now large amplitude) sine wave, so Q1's output is a sine wave with the top half clipped, so Q1's output is close to 800mV most of the time. So Q2 is ON, so the buzzer is ON (C2 removes ripple from Q2's output, so the voltage across the buzzer is stable).
Notes:
The transistors are BC547s.
R4 is to save the buzzer back-voltage destroying Q2.
C2 is to smooth the square-ish wave output of Q2.
The base of Q1 also has a 2.2 nF capacitor connected to 0 V to remove high-frequency noise (I forgot to add this to the diagram).
The transmitter output will be connected to a very long antenna which will be put around the garden perimeter, so that when then cat gets near to the perimeter, the cat will stop (after much training).

Figure 2. Cat collar circuit inside a tic-tac sweet container. The 9V battery is shown for scale.

Figure 3. Cat collar on cat.

Why not first explain the purpose? Is it to open/unlock a cat flap? ie proximity key or shock collar??

Thanks. I have added this text to the top of my post: The overall purpose is to keep a cat in the garden, by making a cat-collar buzzer turn on when the cat gets near to the garden perimeter.

How does the cat know that the buzzing sound means he has to return to base?

Training. Hopefully, he should just avoid places which make the buzzer turn on. Commercial (i.e. expensive) systems work using a collar buzzer, so I am hopeful my cat will read the manual,  and then stay clear of the garden perimeter.

Should use an opamp. Seems to depend on the voltage power supply.

Tried that already, using a TLC274 to amplify, rectify and then compare to a reference voltage to trigger the buzzer. But the area footprint was bigger than the current circuit, and it was less sensitive. Do you mean the trigger point of the buzzer will change as the battery runs down?

Yes, I have simulated it and I have seen that the trigger point "changes" a little as the battery runs down. But perhaps, "bad" simulated.

The trigger point changes, but (hopefully) so does the output of the RF module; but they probably don't change   at the same rate as the battery runs down. I should test this by altering the supply voltage - thanks for pointing this out. Any tips on how to avoid this?

I will make an answer showing what happens at 2 supply voltages. Hope that will be useful.

Reminds me of a the story of a dog fitted with a shock collar and the dog learned that if he flattened his ears and launched himself at the invisible barrier at warp speed he could escape the confinement field to freedom after enduring a moment of pain. Cats like to roam.

KISS Principle: Put up a line across your garden. Put a metal ring on this line and from there another line to the collar. As long as there are no trees in range and some place to seek shade like a bush, this is safe and it works. Used this for my cat during daytime since it was only allowed to roam freely in the evenings.

Btw cats have thyroid glands too so it is questionable whether this is healthy or legal. I'm by no means a vet but I would guess it might be one of the worst possible places on the body to place a RF transmitter. What's the output power? (In Europe this whole thing is definitely illegal regardless, unless you have it tested and CE marked. All products with the potential to harm animals are regarded as safety-critical these days.)

Lundin, The cat collar contains a receiver, not a transmitter. This system uses a standard off-the-shelf radio-control receiver and transmiter module (27MHz); the latter is very low power.

@JamesVStone Oh ok. Still quite a bit questionable all in all. You definitely need an IP67 encapsulation for example, or otherwise this is dangerous for the cat. You didn't even put a fuse in there. I suggest you wear this yourself in the shower before putting it on the cat.

@Lundin The battery is 3.7V (Lipo), what sort of danger to the cat could this represent?

@JamesVStone Any short on the PCB caused by water/moisture which will enter this crappy encapsulation, will use all the current the battery can deliver with no limits and that will burn up the electronics. An escalating temperature next to a Lipo is even worse, it could cause a fire. Do you see why making stuff like this without CE/UKSA testing is illegal? It doesn't matter if it is a commercial product or not.

@Lundin Thanks.

Made with microcap v12
Here is my simulation for 2 supply voltages and 2 input voltages.
NB: I added a transistor (All BC549C) and changed the pot meter by R13.

Update:
After trying this circuit, I modified it a little and simplified it. Added C4.
The sensitivity is ~ 50 mV input. Power supply tested from 3.3 V to 4.2 V.


No advice, but as a former cat owner I am interested to hear whether this device actually works. Cats are mighty contrary creatures.

Antonio, thanks, but where are you making measurements in the circuit? Also, is the extra transistor an improvement (not sure which is the extra one, and why it is needed)?

Fred, Yes, building the circuit may turn out to be the easy part. Training is yet to begin ...

Antonio, thanks (again), but where are you taking measurements from in the circuit? R1 has gone from 200 to 2k in your final circuit - any particular reason for this?

Measurements are taken from an initial condition (power supply of 3.25V, 3.75V, and 4.25V) after applying the generator, in a TRANsient Analysis.  As R1 has gone from 200 to 2k, the circuit is more DC stable. AC gain is highest because this resistor was shorted by the capacitor C4, so the circuit is "more" sensitive. Sensitivity shows to be ~ 50 mV input. BJT used for Q1 has the lowest gain (~200) of the BC547 series.

Antonio, Thanks - I copied your diagram to run the simulation - which was very instructive. But am still unsure where you put the proble to make your measurements.

@JamesVStone The probe is on the Q2 collector, or across the 100 uF capacitor?

@Anotonio51 Thanks. Your comment about the system being voltage dependent caused me to see if it is fail-safe as the battery runs down. But from my simulations, I think the buzzer would tend to switch ON as the battery voltage falls. So, I need to re-design the circuit to ensure that buzzer tends to turn off as the battery voltage gets smaller. Will post the new circuit if/when I get it working.

No worries. It always a pleasure to "serve" ...

Not sure if a human asked if we want to move this to chat, but no need to move to chat - I think we are about done for now.
